# stock arch linux with pv-grub on linode

Tags: xen, grub, linode, arch-linux

I am attempting to use pv-grub on a stock arch linux instance on linode by following this post:-

http://forum.linode.com/viewtopic.php?p=49387

Unfortunately, I am unable to get my pv-grub enabled instance booted up.

Here's the error log I am able to retrieve via `logview` in linode's `lish`.

```
Xen Minimal OS!
start_info:   0xa8d000
  nr_pages:   131072  shared_inf: bf26c000
  pt_base:    0xa90000  mod_start:  0x0
  Booting 'Arch Linux  [/boot/vmlinuz-linux]'

root  (hd0)
 Filesystem type is ext2fs, using whole disk
kernel /boot/vmlinuz-linux root=/dev/xvda ro

close blk: backend at /local/domain/0/backend/vbd/3391/51712
close blk: backend at /local/domain/0/backend/vbd/3391/51728
[21800338.956906] i8042: No controller found
[21800338.998630] drivers/rtc/hctosys.c: unable to open rtc device (rtc0)
[21800338.998818] Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
```

How should I interpret this error and how do I go about fixing this so my pv-grub enabled arch linux instance can now boot properly?

**UPDATE**

I also notice that it claims that the filesystem type is `ext2fs`. Perhaps this is the problem as the disk I created on `linode.com` is in fact using `ext3`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stock arch linux does not work for me and my solution was to custom build my own kernel.

Reference - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37407/learning-how-to-build-my-own-linux-kernel

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone doesn't want to compile their own kernel, the stock kernel in Arch Linux fully supports Xen, paravirtualization, etc. and is perfectly suitable for booting with pv-grub. Here's how you can set it up (Guaranteed to work with `linux-lts 3.10.40-1`):

1. On your Linode, using pacman, install the Linux kernel package of your choice. I suggest  you choose one of the core packages, like `linux` or `linux-lts`. Anything more exotic might not work properly.
2. **Important!** Run `sudo mkinitcpio -p linux`.
3. Using pacman, remove any bootloader packages you might have installed (e.g., `grub` or `syslinux`).
4. Create the file `/boot/grub/menu.lst` with the following contents. You might need to tweak this a little to match your chosen kernel package and Linode disk layout:

   ```sh
   # general configuration:
   timeout   0
   default   0
   hiddenmenu

   # (0) Arch Linux
   title  Arch Linux LTS
   root   (hd0)
   kernel /boot/vmlinuz-linux-lts root=/dev/xvda rw
   initrd /boot/initramfs-linux-lts.img

   # (1) Arch Linux Fallback
   title  Arch Linux LTS - Fallback
   root   (hd0)
   kernel /boot/vmlinuz-linux-lts root=/dev/xvda rw
   initrd /boot/initramfs-linux-lts-fallback.img
   ```
5. Under Linode's dashboard, click **Edit** to change the configuration of your chosen Linode.
6. From **Boot Settings** → **Kernel**, select **pv-grub-x86_64**.
7. Reboot your Linode, and it will boot into your new kernel!